# log4net - Remove old files rolling by date

Tags: log4net

INTENT:

a) I want my logs to be rolled by date in following file format yyyy-MM-dd.txt.

b) Additionally to this I want to remove old files which are out of maxSizeRollBackups range.

> ```
> CAUTION A maximum number of backup files when rolling on date/time 
>   boundaries is not supported. [RollingFileAppender spec][1]
> ```

SOLUTION

for a) is enough to do the configuration

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="logs\" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j"/>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

for b)
Is the inheritance from RollingFileAppender + delete stuff the only way to achieve this ?

Comment: Here is Caution ->
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent some time looking into this a few months ago.  v1.2.10 doesn't support deleting older log files based on rolling by date.  It is on the task list for the next release.  I took the source code and added the functionality myself, and posted it for others if they are interested.  The issue and the patch can be found at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-27 .

Comment: So you added the patch in 2005 and it's still not been accepted yet?!

Comment: (truth be told, it isn't a very active project)  The explanation why is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-27?focusedCommentId=13248077&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13248077

Answer (score 8):

Considering that more than a decade went by and it's still not supported, I opted for the following solution of overriding `RollingFileAppender` with the required functionality:

```
public class RollingDateAppender : RollingFileAppender {
  public TimeSpan MaxAgeRollBackups { get; set; }

  public RollingDateAppender()
    : base() {
    PreserveLogFileNameExtension = true;
    StaticLogFileName = false;
  }

  protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend() {
    base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();

    string LogFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(File);
    var CheckTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(MaxAgeRollBackups);
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(LogFolder, "*.log")) {
      if (System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file) < CheckTime)
        DeleteFile(file);
    }
  }

}
```

Configuration is just as simple as with the original class:

```
roller = new RollingDateAppender {
  AppendToFile = true,
  File = ...;
  MaxAgeRollBackups = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
  RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date,
  ...
};
roller.ActivateOptions();
BasicConfigurator.Configure(roller);
```

Note that looking for `*.log` files in the log directory only makes sense if `PreserveLogFileNameExtension` is used or the `DatePattern` is used to include the extension at the end of the filename. If you need a different naming scheme, modify these in sync.

(I used version 2.0.8 of log4net, earlier versions might not allow the necessary function to be overridden.)

Comment: Will this work with rollingStyle set to 'composite' ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that patch version 4 of RollingFileAppenderer provided here https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12565940/RollingFileAppender.zip works fine with a minor change: in line 1286 replace ".*" with "*".

For this you can use the following configuration:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="MyProduct.log" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'_'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
  <param name="MaxDateRollBackups" value="3" />
  <param name="preserveLogFileNameExtension" value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%r %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```