# How can you delete old log4net logfiles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, log4net

We have an application that logs using log4net.
But we would like to delete the logfiles every 4 weeks (automatically).
Is there an option in log4net to do this or do we need to have a work arround?

Cheers,
M.

this is my configuration

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="Logs/Log4Net/"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd-HH.lo\g" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  </root>
```

Comment: What is your log4net configuration?

Comment: as KMan's answer indicates: removing old logfiles does not work with rolling style = date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290552/log4net-remove-old-files-rolling-by-date/2369451#2369451) doesn't help you, then you can also come up with a windows service that would do the purge-job.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using the windows task scheduler for this job.

Comment: Why Windows Task Scheduler OVER Windows Service ??

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in the program:

```
        string[] logFiles = Directory.GetFiles("Logs\\");
        foreach (string logFile in logFiles)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(logFile);
            if (fileInfo.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
            {
                fileInfo.Delete();
            }
        }
```