# Maxsizerollbackups not working

Tags: log4net

I have to delete logs older than 2 days. My configuration is

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <file value=".\Logs\abc_" />
   <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
   <staticLogFileName value="false" />
   <rollingStyle value="Date" />
   <datePattern value="yyyy.MM.dd'.log'" />
   <appendToFile value="true" />
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="[%property{log4net:HostName}] %date [%thread]      [%-5level] %logger -- %message%newline" />
   </layout>
</appender>
```

But this doesnt seem to work. Please help!

Comment: As documented - [_A maximum number of backup files when rolling on date/time boundaries is not supported_](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4net - Remove old files rolling by date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290552/log4net-remove-old-files-rolling-by-date)

Comment: Do you really need to delete it by date? If you want to limit it by size:  
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />